# python pandas - transforming table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, melt

I would like to transform a table which looks similiar to this below:

> X|Y|Z|
>   1|2|3|
>   3|5|2|
>   4|2|1|

The result, I want to achive, should look like that:

> col|1|2|3|4|5|
>   X  |1|0|1|0|0|
>   Y  |0|2|0|0|1|
>   Z  |1|1|1|0|0|

So,  after transformation the new columns should be unique values from previous table, the new values should be populated with count/appearance, and in the index should be the old column names.

I got stuck and i do not know hot to handle with cause I am a newbe in python, so thanks in advance for support.

Regards,

guddy_7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `apply` with `value_counts`, replace missing values to `0` and transpose by `T`:

```
df = df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int).T
print (df)
   1  2  3  4  5
X  1  0  1  1  0
Y  0  2  0  0  1
Z  1  1  1  0  0
```